# How can I get mailbox in calendar by using ews?

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices

My question is:

```
FolderId confRoomFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(email));
```

Is there any way to list all the emails ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a FindItems() call after instantiating an ExchangeService object, setting credentials there, and doing an Autodiscover().  There are many overloads on FindItems() that allow you to specify search criteria (e.g. time range) and paging options which you'll need to do if you want *all* the emails.
HTH